# Logic: How does if-elif-else fit in to boolean logic?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

How does the if-else if-else conditionals fit in with boolean logic? There's clearly at least 3 outcomes.

If A, output A
elif B, output B
else, output C

Any examples you can provide to help me better understand this basic programming concept would be helpful.

Unless this does not fit with boolean logic then please ignore this.

Comment: If-else statement has to do with boolean logic because it is using boolean variables (variables that have only two possible values: true or false). That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just check if they are true , than use them respectfully.

```
if(A=true)
    echo A;
else
{
    if(B=true)
         echo B;
    else
         echo C;
}
```

This is logic if only one can be true, of course. If you need two of them to be true and 1 false than you can make 2 conditions `if(A=true && B=true)` ... 
edit: 
 For Python and elif the logic is just:

```
if A == true:
   print A
elif B == true:
   print B
elif C == true:
   print C
else:
   print 'All false'
```

The logic is compensation for switch cases that other languages support and Python doesn't
Hope it helps.

Comment: The most important point: The if-elif-else syntax is just a shorthand for the construct in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The two are not really related - if/else is a *flow control* construct which uses the result of a boolean expression to determine which branch to execute.

```
if (X)
    do this stuff when X is TRUE
else
    do this stuff when X is FALSE
```

Of course it's quite common for the controlling expression, X, to contain boolean logic, e.g.

```
if (A && !B || C)
    ...
```

but this is not part of the flow control logic *per se* - it could equally be written:

```
X = A && !B || C;
if (X)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
THIS DIAGRAAM SHOWS IF_ELSEIF_ELSE FLOW CONTROL

if -else if- else links with Boolean expressions as follows

```
 if (expressionA) //if expressionA true then (A)    
       {
       Block of statements;
      }
    else if(expressionB) //If expressionA false then check whether expressionB true/false(NOTA AND B)
      {
       Block of statements;
      }
    else //If expressionA false  and  expressionB false ( NOTA AND NOTB)
      {
        Block of statements;
      }
```